# SharePoint 2019 Calendar List View

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, 2019, calendar-view

On my previous 2013 SharePoint I was able to:

- On a Calendar with recurring events, have a LIST VIEW showing the EXPANDED EVENTS (all individual events broken from in recurrence).

On my new 2019 SharePoint on-premise, I can't get this to work.

- On a classic view - List view only shows an individual record per event.
- The Content Query web part doesn't show all individual events.

Does SharePoint 2019 or modern view support this?

Comment: Are you creating a modern calendar view in SP 2019, similar to this [modern calendar view in SharePoint online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)?

Comment: No, I have migrated a classic calendar from my 2013 site. I require the overlays and recurring events. It is specifically the listing view (not calendar view) of my expanded calendar events that isn’t working. The calendar view is working fine. If you are trying this please try it with a recurring event and edit one of the individual occurrances of that event to break it from the recurrance. Then add a “list vew with expanded events”. It doesn’t show each individual item.